# Read files in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to open a file in Windows Phone 7, but it says it doesn't exist. Here's the code I'm trying:

```
IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
bool test = file.FileExists("\\ClientBin\\clubs.xml");
```

And in my project I added a folder called ClientBin, and the clubs.xml is in there. The clubs.xml file properties are:

Build action: Content
Copy to Output Directory: Copy always

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. You can see what I have in [this screenshot](http://www.screencast.com/users/CarloDekstop/folders/Jing/media/78491236-af3f-4d3c-a387-acf207aea458).

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you ship a file with your application, it doesn't get stored in IsolatedStorage. You need use the conventional way of opening a file that ships with the XAP -

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("ClientBin/customers.xml");
var customers = from query in xdoc.Descendants("Customer")
                select new Customer
                {
                   Name = (string)query.Element("Name"),
                   Employees = (int)query.Element("Employees"),
                   Phone = (string)query.Element("Phone")
                };


// Data bind to listbox
listBox1.ItemsSource = customers;
```

HTH, indyfromoz